# QGIS Processing tools give wrong results

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I want to get a vector layer that would be water area around Europe. Seems easy enough, I got world shoreline, cleaned it up a bit, created a scratch layer on which I put a rectangular polygon to be my bounds:

[image]

Now, I go `Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Difference`. Unfortunately, the result is always somehow wrong:

[image]

No matter what I do, how I draw the rectangle, the northern part is always wrong, sometimes the south and the west are slightly outside of what I set as the bounding rectangle. Do you have any idea what might be causing it? Both layers are set to EPSG:4326 while the project uses ETRS89-extended

Comment: It can't be wrong. Change the project CS to ESPG:4326

Comment: you can try clipping the shoreline polygons first, or to add more vertices to the bounding box polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be a QGIS failure. Change the project CS to ESPG:4326 prior to the process. then it will be OK.

If you desire the project CS to be ETRS89-extended, after the processing.

Comment: +1 for working in a single projection, though QGIS and underlying libraries are not bug-free either :-)

Comment: I reprojected the layers to ETRS89, as I wanted the rectangle to be rectangle in that project and it works! And I guess it's logical, considering on Mercator it looked like this https://i.imgur.com/CBcTkre.png